# phaser "this.game.stage.bounds is undefined"

Tags: phaser-framework

I'm stack with this error in phaser "this.game.stage.bounds is undefined"

```
function create(){
bgtile = game.add.tileSprite(0,350,game.stage.bounds.width,game.cache.getImage('bgtile').heigth, 'bgtile');
```

can anyone help me, thank you :)

Comment: You must provide context (code around it). How else can one diagnose this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just change it to

```
game.stage.getBounds.width
```

and it works :D